# Looking for a Linux GUI frontend to adb which allows me to disable apps on a connected Android device

Tags: android, linux, gui

I'm interested in an application that lets me disable Android apps on a connected (via ADB) device. The functionality I am looking for is basically `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 <pkgname>` and `adb shell pm disable-user <pkgname>`, but with a GUI frontend that shows me more than the shorthand for the apps that is typically to be passed as `<pkgname>`.

The problem is that there are apps for which it's quite obvious what they are about (`com.google.android.apps.duo` or `com.microsoft.skydrive`) and those that are rather cryptic, because they use some code name or abbreviation for the software in question (`com.samsung.android.fmm`).

Comment: Going by your examples it seems your goal is "debloating". So if a GUI is not mandatory, maybe you're interested in [Universal Android Debloater](https://gitlab.com/W1nst0n/universal-android-debloater)? It's just CLI, but from what I understood (I didn't use it myself yet, just found it yesterday) it already does most of the identification part for you.

Comment: @Izzy quite frankly a GUI isn't _strictly_ necessary, but would have been nice. Please write it as an answer. If no alternative comes up, I'll accept it, and in any case I'll upvote it. And yeah, this is about debloating, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main goal is debloating, and the main purpose of the GUI is identifying bloat – then a possible solution is **[Universal Android Debloater](https://gitlab.com/W1nst0n/universal-android-debloater).** It doesn't come with a GUI, but it has the definitions for a bunch of bloat already built-in – bloatware that's specific to some manufacturers, providers and more. It's basically a collection of scripts working with ADB in the way you described – but it saves you from first identifying the bloat on your own.